# openvpn - How to set client to use local gateway? aka use connection for resources on its network only

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, routing, openvpn

sorry for this question, i tried to find a solution but nothing.
I want to configure clients to use local gateway, not server's one.
I just need to configure clients in way that they can see each other, but using local gateways.

here is my server.con file:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-auth ta.key 0
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
```

and client.conf file on server:

```
ifconfig-push 10.8.0.99
```

and here is client.ovpn on client pc:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
remote a.b.c.d 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
setenv opt block-outside-dns
key-direction 1
verb 3
```

when i connect with this configuration, all traffic from client goes via vpn server. and i dont want that.

when on sever i look into /var/log/syslog i find:

```
Nov 16 22:45:11 vpn ovpn-server[16286]: x.x.x.x:40795 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]x.x.x.x:40795, sid=0fbd888b 778a14e6
Nov 16 22:45:11 vpn ovpn-server[16286]: x.x.x.x:40795 CRL CHECK OK: CN=ChangeMe
Nov 16 22:45:11 vpn ovpn-server[16286]: x.x.x.x:40795 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=ChangeMe
Nov 16 22:45:11 vpn ovpn-server[16286]: x.x.x.x:40795 CRL CHECK OK: CN=gerard
Nov 16 22:45:11 vpn ovpn-server[16286]: x.x.x.x:40795 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=gerard
Nov 16 22:45:11 vpn ovpn-server[16286]: x.x.x.x:40795 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
Nov 16 22:45:11 vpn ovpn-server[16286]: x.x.x.x:40795 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC authentication
Nov 16 22:45:11 vpn ovpn-server[16286]: x.x.x.x:40795 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
Nov 16 22:45:11 vpn ovpn-server[16286]: x.x.x.x:40795 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 512 bit message hash 'SHA512' for HMAC authentication
Nov 16 22:45:11 vpn ovpn-server[16286]: x.x.x.x:40795 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
Nov 16 22:45:11 vpn ovpn-server[16286]: x.x.x.x:40795 [gerard] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]x.x.x.x:40795
Nov 16 22:45:11 vpn ovpn-server[16286]: MULTI: new connection by client 'gerard' will cause previous active sessions by this client to be dropped.  Remember to use the --duplicate-cn option if you want multiple clients using the same certificate or username to concurrently connect.
Nov 16 22:45:11 vpn ovpn-server[16286]: MULTI_sva: pool returned IPv4=10.8.0.99, IPv6=(Not enabled)
Nov 16 22:45:11 vpn ovpn-server[16286]: MULTI: Learn: 10.8.0.99 -> gerard/x.x.x.x:40795
Nov 16 22:45:11 vpn ovpn-server[16286]: MULTI: primary virtual IP for gerard/x.x.x.x:40795: 10.8.0.99
Nov 16 22:45:12 vpn ovpn-server[16286]: gerard/x.x.x.x:40795 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'
Nov 16 22:45:12 vpn ovpn-server[16286]: gerard/x.x.x.x:40795 send_push_reply(): safe_cap=940
Nov 16 22:45:12 vpn ovpn-server[16286]: gerard/x.x.x.x:40795 SENT CONTROL [gerard]: 'PUSH_REPLY,route-gateway 10.8.0.1,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.99 255.255.255.0' (status=1)
```

and the end of this file there is **PUSH_REPLY,route-gateway 10.8.0.1** but u didnt set it anywhere.

what am i missing?

please help!

Comment: Please give the entire output of `route print` (upload it somewhere if too long). You apparently miss on the client a route for the LAN, for it not to go via the VPN.

Comment: I edited my question to be more accurate. I hope.

Comment: I want my clients after connecting to VPN to use their own gateways for the internet, and that they are able to see each other on vpn network.

Comment: Consider looking into https://www.softether.org/ if you can or have time. It's much more straight forward and simpler to setup than OpenVPN. It too is Open Source so you can see all the code if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called [Split tunneling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling).

As you have created your own OpenVPN server, you can enable split tunneling on Windows by editing your config files.

Remove `redirect-gateway def1` in your OpenVPN server config file (server.conf). In the client config (client.ovpn or client.conf),
add a line similar to:

```
route 12.12.12.0 255.255.255.0 vpn_gateway
```

This routes the 12.12.12.0 subnet through the VPN connection and everything else out of the non-VPN connection.

Many variations exist on this scenario. If you want to set the VPN as your
default interface, excluding LAN addresses,
then set the VPN as your default gateway,
but add route commands for LAN IPs to go through your local gateway (router etc).

Comment: i dont have `redirect-gateway def1` in my server.conf file. so i added `route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0 10.8.0.1` to client.ovpn. I restarted both client and server, but still my all outgoing connection go via `10.8.0.1`.

Comment: On pptp vpn connection there is an option in windows 'use default gateway on remote network'. if it's not checked i can see computer in vpn lan, and default connection is via local gateway. is there anything similiar in opvnvpn?

Comment: The above route command says that everything from 10.8.0.X should pass via 10.8.0.1. If you wish for it to go elsewhere, specify another gateway.

Comment: You should specify as gateway the one that is used by the devices in your LAN. Typically this is the router.

Comment: If I do this I can no longer connect to other clients even though I have `client-to-client` set. The only thing the `route` does for me is make sure I can connect to localhost via my assigned private ip.